# Android Market app - having a lite version, and other version that breaks policy

Tags: android, google-play, policy

Would my 'lite' version be removed if I have a 'pro' version on my website that breaks Google Play policy? Would Google Play do something like this if I mention my 'pro' version inside of the 'lite' version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Google don't care about this.

It is a market,not a store.